# How can I display a result of data in order by a month-year combine column in sql?

Tags: sql

I want to display a below data in order by first take month and then year

```
count     Date
-------  ----------
 5        Aug 2011 
 6        jan 2008
10        feb 2009
```

I want to result as a first display a 2008 year, then 2009 like wise ordering wise date and also should display month in order wise

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to do?

Comment: Please elaborate.  Show the structure of the table and fields in question and a listing of sample output.

Comment: give some more information about the structure and expected result

Comment: What was the solution?  Post it as an answer and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution..

```
select convert(char(3), Date, 0)+'  '+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(Date)), 4) as [Date]
,count(id) as Count from Tabletest 
 group by convert(char(3), Date, 0)+'  '+ RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(Date)), 4),month(Date),YEAR(Date)
order by YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- You are trying to count records grouping by year and month
- You have a table named `Table1` with a column named `EventDate`
- You are using SQL Server (you didn't specify)
- You don't mind having extra columns in the output (you can ignore the columns you don't need)
- You want to order by count, then year, then month

Based on these assumptions, the following should give you what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count,
        CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, EventDate))
                + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(EventDate)) AS Date,
        MIN(YEAR(EventDate)) AS Year, MIN(MONTH(EventDate)) AS Month
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(EventDate)),
                CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, EventDate))
        ORDER BY COUNT(*), Year, Month
```